# Photo doesn't appear in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, type-conversion

I selected multi photo from gallery and show in GridView. All are ok, it take 3 item area when I select 3 photos, but photo doesn't show in GridView. I think data type convert problem.

Here is Pick Photo from Gallery Activity

```
if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    List<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
   // StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    /*for (Photo photo: mPhotos) {
        System.out.println(photo.getPhoto());
    }*/
    for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
        Photo photos = new Photo();
        photos.setPhoto(String.valueOf(i));
        mPhotos.add(photos);
        stringBuffer.append(images.get(i).path + "\n");
    }
    Log.i("SS", stringBuffer.toString());
    //  textView.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
}
```

Here is Adapter

```
public class SelectPhotoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Photo> mPhotos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public SelectPhotoAdapter(Context context, List<Photo> mPhotos) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mPhotos = mPhotos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPhotos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Photo getItem(int position) {
        return mPhotos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return Integer.valueOf(mPhotos.get(position).photo);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ImageView picture;

        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        }

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        Photo photo = getItem(position);
        picture.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(photo.getPhoto()));
        return v;
    }
}
```

Here is xml

```
<com.example.android.SquareImageView
android:id="@+id/picture"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Comment: post the xml : `gridview_item`

Comment: `photo.getPhoto())` does it give a valid Resource id?

Comment: Yes, can't setImageResource(photo.getPhoto())

Comment: try to set a defult imageview `picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample);` to your picture if the image shows then problem lies in your `photo.getPhoto()` attribute

Comment: When I use Log.i inside for loop,  **Log.i("PATH", images.get(i).path);** It show path (I/PATH: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1487742093532.jpg ...) 3 select, 3 path show, I think sth wrong, to carry data to adapter

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I use Drawable, It shows

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getPhoto());

    // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
    picture.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: have you declared permission in manifest?                                                          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Yes, I declared permission. I think sth wrong at **photos.setPhoto()** It is path. **stringBuffer.toString()**

Comment: replace  Photo photo = getItem(position); with Photo photo = mPhotos.get(position);